# Triple monitors with ATI and nVidia card - was working, now confused

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-graphics-card

I had a triple monitor setup working in Windows 7 with an ATI card as my primary and a cheap nVidia card as my secondary. The ATI card powered two monitors and the nVidia powered the third. Everything was working fine.

Then I rebuilt. Now I can't seem to get all three monitors activated to save my life. I don't know if I need to uninstall and reinstall drivers in a certain order or what - but the key here is that I had it working for months. I don't recall any problems making it work originally, so I hope it's just something I'm overlooking.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

**EDIT**: Well crap - I decided to try one more time to enable the third monitor ("extend desktop to this display") and this time it worked - go figure. I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if anyone can contribute ideas for proper implementation using different manufacturers.

Comment: I have a similar problem, yet it didn't resolved by itself. There is a slight difference - I have one Ati card that supports up to 4 monitors and has a TV out. I had it working for months on two monitors and a TV, but after update of windows and graphic card drivers it stopped working. I've tried to change drivers back, but it didn't helped.

Comment: I've resolved my problem too. I had two rows of dvi connectors. I had just plugged monitors to different rows and a tv to the tv out. Now it works smoothly.